# AngularJs button loses scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am having a $scope issue with a button on my page.  There is a ui-grid on the page.  When the "Add New" button is clicked it hides the grid and shows a div that allows the user to input a new record.  Once the user clicks the "Save" button to save the information they have entered, the screen goes back to its original state with the grid showing and the other div hidden.  The problem is that I can no longer click the "Add New" button again because it has lost its $scope.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myModule" ng-controller="OperatorCtrl">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">Business Unit Administration</div>
        <div class="panel-body">

            <div ng-hide="noView">

                @Html.Label("Edit a Business Unit belo0w to assign Users and Contractors")
                <div>
                    <div ui-grid="gridOptions" class="grid" ng-style="{height: (gridOptions.data.length*30)+32+'px'}" ui-grid-auto-resize></div>

                </div>
                <div class="pull-right">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style="width:100px" ng-click="addNew()">Add New</button>
                </div>
            </div>
 <div ng-show="noView">
                <form name="AddBusinessUnitForm">
                    <table style="width:100%">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Business Unit Name</th>
                                <th>Operator System ID</th>
                                <th>Action</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td><input type="text" style="width:200px" ng-model="form.vchDescription" /></td>
                                <td><input type="text" style="width:300px" ng-model="form.vchOperatorSystemID" /></td>
                                <td ng-show="addNew"><button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" ng-click="saveNew()">Save</button></td>
                                <td>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style="width:100px" ng-click="return()">Close</button>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </form>
```

The "Add New" and "Close" buttons only toggle the "noView" variable to show and hide each section.

Here is my Angular:

```
$scope.addNew = function () {
    $scope.noView = true;

};

$scope.saveNew = function () {
    $scope.businessUnitName = $scope.form.vchDescription;
    operatorService.savenew($scope.form)
    .success(function (data) {
        $scope.businessUnitID = data;
        getUsers($scope.businessUnitID);
        $scope.viewTabs = true;
        $scope.addNew = false;
    });
};
$scope.return = function () {
    $scope.noView = false;
```

};

I'm new to Angular and am not sure how to maintain the button's scope.

ANY assistance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: It's a very BAD idea to name a function or a variable the same as a reserved word... Try changing the name of $scope.return

Comment: Have you verified that $scope.saveNew is not being invoked when you click the button, as opposed to the code simply not behaving as you expect?

Comment: All the buttons behave as expected  accept the "Add New" button which no longer executes after the first click.  I have to hit F5 to refresh the browser for it to execute again.  I actually see a Javascript run time error in the output window of VS which says "Function expected" when I click it a second time.

Answer (score 1):

In your html you aren't passing anything into the function that utilizes ng-click. There's nothing being saved because there is nothing to save. I hope this helped.

Comment: Have you tried removing  $scope.addNew = false; ? Because as far as I can tell there isn't anything making .addNew to be true again...

Comment: THANK YOU!  That was the problem!

Comment: woo hoo! lucky guess really on my part :P but i'm glad it works now

I'm new to angularJS / webdev myself, but I learned something new myself, you can set functions to false and therefore make them not run.... I don't remember this being mentioned in the angularJS dev guide...

Comment: The problem was that I named the function and a variable I was trying to use to show/hide the same thing!  LOL!  Silly mistake, but needed a fresh pair of eyes looking at it.  But you just taught me something.  I didn't know that you could set functions to false to make them not run.  Great catch!

Comment: I'm now wondering how you can make $scope.addNew be the original function that it was after you made it false.

However, I guess you could have a $scope.addNew_Copy be the same as $scope.addNew and use it to write over .addNew after you've made it false. Not sure though.